# Run- Time Error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

In summary, the code below copies all the information on a sheet and pastes the information on a new excel sheet while keeping the formatting. That document is then saved with the naming convention of the active sheet name and the current date. This sheet is saved in two places and then closes itself. When I run the code all the steps occur but the document does not save into the two folders and the error message pops up and stops the code there. Can you please check out my code and see why it does not work? Thank you in advance!

```
Sub SaveXLST()
'
' SaveXLST Macro
'
Dim monthVal As Integer
Dim mVal As String
Dim dayVal As Integer
Dim dVal As String
Dim yearVal As Integer
Dim yVal As String

monthVal = Month(Date)
dayVal = Day(Date)
yearVal = Year(Date)

If monthVal < 10 Then
   mVal = "0" & monthVal
Else
   mVal = "" & monthVal
End If

If dayVal < 10 Then
   dVal = "0" & dayVal
Else
   dVal = "" & dayVal
End If

Cells.Select
Range("A9").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ChDir "N:\D\IG\C\~ P"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "N:\D\IG\C\~P\T" & "-" & yearVal & "." & mVal & "." & dVal, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ChDir "N:\D\IG\C\T"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "N:\D\IG\C\T\T" & "-" & yearVal & "." & mVal & "." & dVal, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see at which line is the error coming?

Comment: Error occurs right after Cells.Select

Comment: So at `Range("A9").Activate`? That seems to be all right. Try stepping through your code with F8 while looking at the Excel worksheet (2nd monitor or one side of the screen) and see what goes wrong.

Comment: After doing some reading there might be a problem with the cells.select? When running through the program it seems to do everything, which is copying the information then pasting it on a new excel sheet, but it is not saving down at the individual place. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You shouldn't need Cells.Select - maybe try removing that?

Comment: The problem is that Excel does not now on which page it should look.  When using multiple pages one should qualify the range witht he correct parentage.  For example `Workbooks("MyWorkBook").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").Copy` .  When using the macro recorder it is assumed the active sheet, but when reusing it a lot of times Excel will get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with some minor adjustments / improvements (including the ones suggested by @ScottCraner and @Charlie in their comments).

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveXLST()
'
' SaveXLST Macro
'
Dim monthVal As Integer
Dim dayVal As Integer
Dim yearVal As Integer
Dim xlsNewFile As Workbook

monthVal = Month(Date)
dayVal = Day(Date)
yearVal = Year(Date)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Indicate here from which sheet you want to copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").Copy
Set xlsNewFile = Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Application.CutCopyMode = False
If Dir("c:\tmp", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
'If Dir("N:\D\IG\C\~ P", vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "No such path: N:\D\IG\C\~ P" & Chr(10) & "Skipping first save!"
Else
    xlsNewFile.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "c:\tmp\" & "-" & yearVal & "." & Format(monthVal, "00") & "." & Format(dayVal, "00") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If


If Dir("N:\D\IG\C\T\T", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "No such path: N:\D\IG\C\T\T" & Chr(10) & "Not saving to second location!"
Else
    xlsNewFile.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "N:\D\IG\C\T\T" & yearVal & "." & Format(monthVal, "00") & "." & Format(dayVal, "00") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If

xlsNewFile.Close

End Sub
```

Let me know if this solved your problems / errors.

Comment: Hi gentleman, I wand to just thank you for spending time to help me out with this problem. I am still relatively new to excel and your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: after using the new code, with executed, there is a new excel sheet that pops up but it is blank, so I am not sure if it copied the values over. This is then followed by the two message boxes. Please assist.